# wait4 do not block parent thread

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I have two following source files

loop.c which executable name is `loop`

```
int main() {
    while(true);
    return 0;
}
```

and run.c which executable name is `run`

```
int main() {
    pid_t child_pid = fork();

    int status;
    struct rusage info;

    if (child_pid == 0) {
        ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, NULL, NULL);
        execl("loop", "loop", NULL);
        exit(0);
    }

    wait4(child_pid, &status, 0, &info);

    puts("Child exited");
    printf("%ld\n", info.ru_utime.tv_usec);

    return 0;
}
```

I've compiled both and I've ran `run` program. Why it terminated? I've read that wait4 [suspend](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl2_wait4.htm), but in fact it does not. When I've executed `ps` program `loop` is running and `run` does not (it's not in `ps` and terminal seems to finish it's work by giving an output).

Am I missing something?

PS

I used gnu g++ compiler if it's matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose the problem is here

```
ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

and here

```
wait4(child_pid, &status, 0, &info);
```

wait4 (deprecated by the way) return control if process state changed.

ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME force child send to parent SIGTRAP if some condition
happen, and every time wait4, waitpid and similar functions return control to you,
you need use WIFEXITED to distinguish between exit of child process and sigtrap condition.

You can check my statement by replacing wait4 call with:

```
    if (wait4(child_pid, &status, 0, &info) < 0) {
        perror("wait4 failed");
    } else if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
        printf("process exit\n");
    } else
        printf("child just send signal\n");
```

Comment: Thanks for advice I wrapped up wait4 in infinity loop and in fact it runs once. What should I use instead of wait4 by the way? I really need to know time of execution of child thread.

Comment: In your variant you can use getrusage(RUSAGE_CHILDREN.

Comment: By the way you can find working program with similar pattern ptrace + waitpid, but this programs works, here: http://habrahabr.ru/post/111266/ . This about tracing system calls. Even if you don't know Russian language, the C code in article will be enough to get idea.

Comment: Thank you now I understand how to deal with my problem. Voted as best ans.

Comment: I have an extra question if possible for you too answer. I have problem with tracing java program, I believe it's due to "java vm magic". I replaced `execl` with `execlp("java", "java", "-jar", "hello.jar", NULL);` which basically runs hello world program, but no syscall 4 appeared. Any clues?

Comment: If problem in finding out what syscall used by "java -jar ...", you can run it like this "strace -f jave -jar .."

Comment: It's not exact my intent I need to check what syscalls hello.jar program make and would like to do it similar to ptrace does - one by one with breakpoints. java -jar is just to run hello.jar


I'm assuming that there is no syscall nr 4 due to exec runs jvm, which runs some internal threads and then I loose thread which executes program "off sight". Is there any chance to find it?

Comment: I don't understand what you want. You write that you want to check what syscalls do "java". strace utlity do exactly what you want show all syscalls in process, all his threads, and in child processes if you want. You want do it by your self, ok, first check that "strace" works, then look at its source code, it (strace) uses ptrace internaly and use the same algorithm as strace.