# ptrace Java program using C/C++

Tags: java, c, linux, system-calls, ptrace

I have problem similar to my previous one presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17689125/wait4-do-not-block-parent-thread).

This time I want use program written in c/c++ to track execution of JAVA program. So as I stated before same code which track stdout printing for c/c++ and register syscall 4 haven't done it for JAVA. I assume it's because execlp which I trace is used just to run jvm. And later on there are created more processes (by inner mechanism of jvm) which I do not track. I found this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477976/how-to-ptrace-a-multi-threaded-application) which seems to be partial solution. If I got it right every child will be traced. But that's is a problem as well I want to track only that process which handles my application and not all others that jvm might create. Is there any chance to get know which jvm thread/process handles my program and track only it?

For make it a bit easier let's assume my JAVA program is one-thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you start the binary through your tracer app, all threads will be traced.

But if you attach to a process, then you won't attach to all it's threads. You have to attach to all of its threads using the threadids, that you can found listed eg. in /proc/%d/task/.

Also, I suggest reading through strace's source code, I've learnt a lot from it. If you can use strace to successfully follow java threads as you want, you can get the logic from it.